Is a Peltier's cooling power included in volts * amperage?
Say there is a 12 volt, 12 ampere peltier module, the cooling power of which is 100 watts. Does that mean that the hot side produces 12 * 12 + 100 = 144 + 100 = 244 watts
Or
12 * 12 = 144 watts?

no, these are less than 100% efficient, I think like 15%, you can look it up.
